# What is the modern programming standard for synchronizing data between a web service and a client?

Tags: web-services, rest, synchronization, data-synchronization

The question is a little general, so to help narrow the focus, I'll share my current setup that is motivating this question. I have a LAMP web service running a RESTful API. We have two client implementations: one browser-based javascript client (local storage store) and one iOS-based client (core data store). Obviously these two clients store data very differently, but the data itself needs to be kept in two-way sync with the remote server as often as possible.

Currently, our "sync" process is a little dumb (as in, non-smart). Conceptually, it looks like:

- Client periodically asks the server for ALL of the most-recent data.
- Server sends down the remote data, which overwrites the current set of local data in the client's store.
- Any local creates/updates/deletes after this point are treated as gold, and immediately sent to the server.

The data itself is stored relationally, and updated occasionally by client users. The clients in my specific case don't care too much about the relationships themselves (which is why we can get away with local storage in the browser client for now).

Obviously this isn't true synchronization. I want to move to a system where, conceptually, a "diff" of the most recent changes are sent to the server periodically, and the server sends back a "diff" of the most recent changes it knows about. It seems very difficult to get to this point, but maybe I just don't understand the problem very well.

[REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) feels like a good start, but REST only talks about the way two data stores talk to each other, not how the data itself is synchronized between them. (This sync process is left up to the implementer of each store.) What is the best way to implement this process? Is there a modern set of programming design patterns that apply to inform a specific solution to this problem? I'm mostly interested in a general (technology agnostic) approach if possible... but specific frameworks would be useful to look at too, if they exist.

Comment: I feel like this is one of the big modern-day programming challenges that I wish I had learned about in school. The general problem really seems complex enough to warrant an entire semester of study. I just want to know how to do it right!

Comment: Can you talk a little bit more about the data itself... how is it structured? How often is it changed?  What prompts changes (user-initiated or app/server initiated)?

Comment: The data itself is stored relationally, and updated occasionally by client users. I've updated the question to add a bit about that.

Comment: Crude, but I've done it like this before: server generates latest data as JSON file, client's browser loads this and generates (page, whatever), changes on client generate new JSON file (on given trigger), server script reads client's new JSON and updates db. A little browser storage helps preserve state on client.

Comment: You should be asking yourself what happens when two conflicting changes are send to the service at the same time. That key question guides a lot of the design.

Comment: @DonalFellows - Complexities like conflict resolution are the part of the reason "true" sync seems very difficult to implement. I understand that answering those questions are an important part of the process, but I'm trying to determine the *best* way forward based on patterns or de facto standards.

Answer (score 4):

Multi-master replication is always (and will always be) difficult and bespoke, because how conflicts are handled will be specific to your application.

IMO A more robust approach is to use Master-slave replication, with your web service as the master and the clients as slaves. To keep the clients in sync, use an archived atom feed of the changes (see [event sourcing)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) as per [RFC5005](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-4). This is the closest you'll get to a modern standard for this type of replication and it's RESTful.

When the clients are online, they do not update their replica directly, instead they send commands to the server and have their replica updated via the atom feed.

When the clients are offline things get difficult. Your clients will need to have a model of how your web service behaves. It will need to have an offline copy of your replica, which should be [copied on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) from the online replica (the online replica is the one that is updated by the atom feed). When the client executes commands that modify the data, it should store the command (for later replay against the web service), the expected result (for verification during replay) and update the offline replica.

When the client goes back online, it should replay the commands, compare the result with the expected result and notify the client of any variances. How these variances are handled will vary based on your application. The offline replica can then be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB replication works over HTTP and does what you are looking to do.  Once databases are synced on either end it will send diffs for adds/updates/deletes.

Couch can do this with other Couch machines or with a mobile framework like TouchDB.

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS

I've done a fair amount of it, but you can always set up CouchDB on one machine, set up TouchDB on a mobile device and then watch the HTTP traffic go back and forth to get an idea of how they do it.

Or read this: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html

Maybe something from the link above will help you get an idea of how to do your own diffs for your REST service.  (Since they are both over HTTP thought it could be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the Dropbox Datastore API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore

It sounds like it might be a very good fit for your purposes.  They have iOS and javascript clients.

Comment: Does that require all of your data to be stored "in the dropbox cloud"? I don't see any server component to pull data from, so I'm not sure it would work for my purpose. I can't convert my web service into a dropbox app...

Comment: Datastore has been [depreciated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/) since April, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Lately, I've been interested in [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/).

The platform sets up [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.com/) on the server and minimongo in the browser.  The client subscribes to some data and when that data changes, the platform automatically sends down the new data to the client.

It's a clever solution to the syncing problem, and it solves several other problems as well.  It will be interesting to see if more platforms do this in the future.